# Check if device is jailbroken/rooted using Jail Monkey in React Native fails module is 'undefined'

Tags: react-native, package.json, jailbreak

In React Native I found two plugins to check if a device (iOS/Android) is jailbroken/rooted:

1. [Jail Monkey](https://github.com/GantMan/jail-monkey/blob/master/README.md)
2. [react-native-is-device-rooted](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-is-device-rooted)

I have firstly tried the npm package **react-native-is-device-rooted** but it doesn't work and it seems to be outdated. So I tried Jail Monkey, but I get this following error:

[image]

The code is:

```
import JailMonkey from 'jail-monkey'

export default class Welcome extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
                ...
                <View style={styles.lowerView}>
                    <CustomButton text={"Jail Monkey"} onPress={() => this.printJailMonkey()}/>
                </View>
                ...
        );
    }

    printJailMonkey = () => {
        console.log("Jail Monkey library content: " + JailMonkey.isJailBroken())
    }
}
```

I have checked carefully the manual link of the package (using Xcode, pod install, and so on...). Nothing worked, does someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved but doing manually the linking.

Comment: Hi, I've been debugging for some time now. Can you remember what you did here when you said manual linking? react-native link doesnt update my podfile, when i add pod 'jail-monkey' I get double react-native imports. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JailMonkey uses Native Modules and thus cannot run in an Expo managed app. You need to eject it to ExpoKit for JailMonkey to work.

Comment: I am not using Expo.

Comment: This answer is outdated. JailMonkey should work fine with an Expo managed app as long as you build with [EAS Build](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/)

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps for manual linking.
Navigate to root folder in terminal enter commands:

1. `react-native link`
2. `cd ios`
3. `pod update`